# Python Beautifulsoup : how to find a tag by attribute value without knowing corresponding attribute name?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Let's assume we have an Attribute value "xyz" without knowing the Attribute Name. It means we could match

```
    <a href="xyz">
```

but also

```
    <div class="xyz">
```

Is it possible search for such tags?

Comment: do you have any list of candidate for attribute names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is using `lambda` in `find_all` function.

Example:

```
data = '''<a href="xyz">a</a>
<div class="somethingelse">b</div>
<div class="xyz">c</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: any('xyz' in tag[a] for a in tag.attrs)):
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
<a href="xyz">a</a>
<div class="xyz">c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tag for tag in soup.find_all(True) 
    if "xyz" in tag.attrs.values() or ["xyz"] in tag.attrs.values()]
```

The explanation:

- `soup.find_all(True)` finds *all tags* (because `True` is for every tag evaluated to `True`).
- `tag.attrs` is the dictionary of all attributes of the `tag`.
- We are not interested in tag attributes *names* (as `href`, `class`, `id`), only in their *values* - so we use `tag.attrs.values()`.
- Some attributes are multi-valued (e.g. `class="x y"`), so their value in the `attrs` dictionary is a list (e.g. `["x", "y"]`). So we test both `"xyz"` and `["xyz"]` possibilities.